# Comma Separated Data in Google Visualisation API

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, google-visualization

I'm using GeoChart from the Google Visualisation API to create a dynamic map containing site usage information. Due to the large metric values (8 digits), I need to comma separate these numbers to make the map more readable. I've written a function that adds commas to these number, but this then causes errors with the API drawing the map.

For example, when comma separating 1 of the 3 columns of data (Country, Visits, Unique Visitors), the label for that column will be removed in the country tool tips. Comma separating 2 of the columns then leads to the entire map failing, with an 'Expecting 2 columns' error. This must be due to the commas in the number string not being escaped and therefore causing errors in the JSON array. I've tried inserting `'\,'` instead of a regular comma to no avail. Any work arounds or solutions?

Comment: can you include snapshot for these various error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a step back I think the better way to solve the problem is to format your raw data using the NumberFormat class in google visualizations called google.visualization.NumberFormat.  More info here: [google.visualization.NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter)

Here is an example of how to format the 2nd column to have commas as the grouping separator:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 60000000000000000],
    ['RU', 700]
  ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'###,###'} );
  formatter.format(data, 1);
  
  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347, tooltip: {textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: '15'}}});
}
```

I used the [google visualization playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_chart) to test it out.

### Update

Modified the geochart.draw line to include tooltip text styling.  It will style the all of the text in the tooltip.  I haven't seen anyway to make fine grain customizations. Here is more info: [Geochart Configuration Options](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Configuration_Options)

Comment: This looks very promising indeed - I'll take a look in the morning when I get into the office, thanks.

Comment: On another note, do you know any ways to format items within the country popover in terms of colour or font style?

Comment: You are welcome! I updated the solution to include the styling of the popover.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official specification for the CSV file format, including commas in data is possible by wrapping the data in double-quotes.

[Basic rules and examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples):

Any field may be quoted (that is, enclosed within double-quote characters). Some fields must be quoted, as specified in following rules.

```
"1997","Ford","E350"
```

Fields with embedded commas must be quoted.

```
1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"
```